# The usage of multiline comments in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Is it just a luxury os it there a real usage of multiline comments in Kotlin?

```
/* This is a comment.

 /* And inside it
 is
 another comment.
 */

 Back to the first.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking about multi-line comments *within* multi-line comments, right?

Imagine you have a big function that has a multi-line comment inside it. Then you want to comment out this whole function. You can surround it with `/*` and `*/` and it will correctly comment the whole function even though there is a `*/` inside it. It can detect that it's an interior comment by its preceding `*/`. This is why it's necessary for a multi-line comment to allow nested multi-line comments within itself.

Comment: And this differs from Java, which does _not_ support nested multi-line comments — and where commenting out large sections of code is far harder as a result.